# browser will not pick up css for div element unless I put in a fake css before it

Tags: css

I am linking a CSS file to a django app page. The HTML is from ajax, some of the css is getting applied, but most is not. For example, at the top of the CSS file I have the following:

```
$green: #86BB71;
$blue: #94C2ED;
$orange: #E38968;
$gray: #92959E;

div.nothingdiv{}


div#fav_studyspot_chat{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 750px;
  background: #444753;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

The second div only works after I put in the nothingdiv. Can anybody explain what that would happen?

Comment: I just figured out this is SCSS, not CSS.  It's the first time I've seen this, I'll dig further into it.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `$`-prefixed variables isn’t supported natively in CSS: it’s a feature of CSS compilers such as Sass and Less. In CSS, the only top-level declarations you can write are:

- selectors, which describe elements (e.g. via class names, IDs, or element names)
- media queries, which describe different styles under different conditions
- keyframes, which describe animations
- and imports, which allow you to import other style sheets

When a browser encounters code that isn’t one of these kinds in CSS, it ignores it until it encounters code it understands, which usually means waiting until it encounters curly braces that denote the end of a declaration `}`.

If you remove all the variables with the dollar signs in front of them, your code should work even without the fake styles.

If you want to use variables in CSS, and not have to have them compiled by Sass or Less, you should use custom properties, which look like this:

```css
:root {
  --green: #86BB71;
}

.element {
  color: var(--green);
}
```